# How can I have presets for multiple render options?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I've been working on a huge scene and i'm using the quick render feature a lot. but i'm always stuck with one option to render with all the time if i want to change settings such as sampling,performance, light paths settings and i have to go and adjust these numbers manually. 
i usually render my quick render with lower light paths number but when i want to get an actual render i have to go back to these numbers change them again and i always forget what were the initial numbers.

Is there anyway i can have multiple rendering options presets, let say one for testing, one for quick render one for production. so far the only value i know i can change is sampling for quick render and final render.

is there any addon for it , or is it hard to write addon myself?

one suggestion i got was to have multiple scene but if i change anything in one scene i have to copy it across and it's more time spending moving stuff around.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked, and when I create a new scene and 'link objects' then I can switch between scenes and the position of my object is the same in both if I move it on one or the other. If I use 'Link Object Data' then the objects are there but they are only moved in the scene where I made the movement, and in original position in the other.Maybe choosing 'Link Objects' can let you share the objects and then make the settings locally for render different then.

An addon or script is not that hard to make yourself if you look at simple examples for making your own operator that acts as a macro to perform some action or change a setting. [cgcookie intial python scrtipting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZWSvUgR38Y) and [cgcookie setting up custom panel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j75AM1Mttc). These are only two examples of all kinds of stuff you can find on the internet, and depending on how you want to access your script you might even just keep it handy to call up and run when you want to from the text editor, or go so far as to make a custom addon panel for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I wrote that should do the trick:
https://github.com/blendfx/blender/blob/master/render_tweaker.py 
You can either store render settings settings manually, or enable slot recording (in image editor), which will store the current settings of each render in each render slot.

Here's a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3FI_n6vH64